# Few questions on my project (Schematics) -> resistor, transistor

Tags: voltage, led, transistors, resistors, schematics

I have a school project where I have an electronic circuit connected to a microprocessor, with a thermometer controlling LEDs, and buttons changing the date, etc.
I made a quick schematics (orange arrows go to the microprocessor which takes 3.3V maximum)
[image]

So my questions are :

- Is there something stupid I made ?
- Do I need any resistor in that system ?
- Can I control the 5V entry with a transistor from the 3.3V entry ?

References :

[Thermometer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) (generates 10mV / degree Celcius)

[Analogic to Digital Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc548.pdf)

[Button Switch](http://www.jameco.com/z/R13-81-R-Push-ButtOn-Switch-Off-Momentary-On-Single-Pole-Single-Throw-Round-Plunger-0-5-Amp-125-Volt-AC-COntact-Pc-Pins-Panel-Mount-Through-Hole_315643.html)

[Transistor](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FQP30N06L-1009543.pdf) (The one I need to use if I implement it)

Unfortunately I have no information about the power needed by my leds, but I guess it should be around 3V.

I hope this isn't too messy, thanks for help !

Comment: Nothing is controlling your LEDs.

Comment: How is the thermometer controlling the LEDs? It looks like they are connected directly between the supply rails without any switching circuitry. If this is the case, they will definitely need resistors. (220 or 330 ohm should work well)

Comment: That is more like a block diagram than a schematic.  You do need current-limiting resistors in series with the LEDs, and probably pull-down resistors on the push-button inputs to the microcontroller.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams The microprocessor is supplying the 3.3V, it gets informations from the thermometer and then supplies it to the leds and buttons.

Comment: @PeterBennett The push buttons take between 0 and 125V so I thought they would work anyway. The leds are controlled by the microprocessor, actually my schematics is a bit wrong because they have seperated entries from the buttons. And sorry, I'm not english native and don't know the difference between a block diagram and a schematics haha

Comment: The microcontroller button inputs will need pull-down resistors to ensure that the inputs will be seen as Low when the buttons are not pressed.

Comment: I fixed the schematics.

Comment: @PeterBennett What should be the value of these resistors ? I feel like I need resistors at the entry of every button and led but I'm not sure about the value they should have... I know it is R = U / I, but I'm not sure about how that really works... Buttons take I = 0.5A I think. I don't know for the leds.

Comment: That's still a block diagram - a schematic will show the exact details of all connections.  Pull-down resistors on the microcontroller inputs can be 10K or so.  The LED resistor values depend on the LED forward voltage, and your desired current/brightness.  510 Ohms might be a good starting point.  Lots of info on the web, and here, about LED resistor values.

Comment: @PeterBennet I will try to find the right values for the resistors on the Leeds. However, what would happen if I don't put any resistor on button inputs ? I saw they have to take 0.5A, should I take it into my calculations ? For example I thought of taking a resistor of u/I = 3.3/0.5 = 6.6 ohm for the buttons, is that right ?

Comment: The microcontroller inputs are very high impedance - if left unconnected (as when the button is open) they will float randomly between High and Low.  A pull-down resistor will ensure the input is Low when the button is not pulling it High.  The 0.5 A rating on the switch is the maximum current the switch can safely handle - you don't need to pass that much current through the switch.

Comment: @PeterBennett I see, thanks a lot for these informations ! :) So, to resume it, I will need a pull down resistor with a value that doesn't mind - you said 10K earlier, I will see what my school can provide me - connected to the buttons, and a normal resistor of around 220 ohm connected to the leds. I don't need a resistor connected to the thermometer or the ADC right ? Thanks again !